# Android app organisation

Tags: android, design-patterns, structure

I'm currently doing an app that will be "duplicated" for many project.
The only thing that will be change for each projects, is the design (some pictures and texts).

I'm wondering if it's correct to split the project in modules, like :

- app (the root of the app, with layouts and activities)
- model (generic database)
- io (tools for getting webservices, or check network connection)
- map (manage mapView)

Thank you !

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use different build variants. 
Each build variant will have it's own resources. 
Than you compile each one you need separately - generating different .apk files.

Look here:
[Work with build variants](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants)

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's look exactly what I want, I will try